# How to find the measurement of a certain diagonal in a regular nonagon?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

> Points $A, B, C$ and $D$ are four consecutive vertices of a regular nonagon with sides 25mm long. Find the length of $AD$.

Here's what I have so far:

[image]

I believe I've taken the right steps, but I'm not sure how to proceed. I don't think we can solve for $AE$ or $ED$ using the trigonometric ratios as we don't have enough info (or do we?). How do I finish this problem?

Comment: Your work seems to suggest that angle ABC is 60 degrees. Why do you think this?

Comment: (9 – 2)180 = 1260       1260 / 9 = 140      My bad.

Answer (score 4):

Your method *would* lead to the right solution, but it is unnecessarily complicated. We solve the problem in two steps.

[image]

Both the blue and black triangles are right-angled. The blue angle is 20°, so the circumradius (black hypotenuse; distance from any vertex to centre of nonagon) is $(25/2)/\sin20^\circ=36.547\text{ mm}$. The black angle is 60°, so half the chord length (half of $AD$) is $36.547\sin60^\circ=31.651\text{ mm}$. Then $AD$ is twice this, or $63.302\text{ mm}$.